# Header position issue for popup overlay

Tags: css

I am working in angular 2. My html page have header div and popup overlay div.we are facing z-index issue when i opening my popup overlay is not applying for header div only.I want to apply overlay hole window when i opening popup.If i change my header position is inherit then it will work but i wont change my header position because header is fixed position.How to resolve this problem?

HTML:

```
header-component

 <div class="myheader"> 
 ..menus 
 </div>
```

popup-component

```
<div class="popup"></div> 
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

CSS

```
 .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0; 
    z-index: 106; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#fff;
    opacity:.60;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60);filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    }   

    .myheader{ 
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
```

Comment: Try giving z-index of overlay a higher value, maybe `999`? Because now `.myheader` and `.overlay` have the same z-index - `100`

Comment: Please share html code as well (or part of it where issue can be seen). As the 2 classes have the same z-index, the order of the related div in the dom can be related to your problem

Comment: Updated html...this issue in angular 2

Comment: I can not find out the reason.It is working only if i change .myheader position 'inherit'..but this is not correct.if i chnage like this i will get extra scroll and header is moving..

Comment: Please help me anyone..

Answer (score 0):

I've taken out some of the code to show you if you just change the z-index, it works fine. Whichever `<div>` has the higher `z-index` will be on top.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.overlay, .myheader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 98; 
  color: white;
  background:black;
}   

.myheader { 
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.overlay, .myheader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 98; 
  color: white;
  background:black;
}   

.myheader { 
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">Things</div>
<div class="myheader">Stuff</div>
```

Comment: Fencepencil: Already i have tried like this..but not working...I am facing position issue also

Comment: Z-index only working if i change myheader position:inherit..but i want fixed header.

Comment: I think problem is myheader and overlay is fixed position

Comment: Do you have a live example of what you are trying to achieve? We might be able to get at it from a different angle(ular) <- pun

Comment: Give few minutes

Comment: I can not create any example

Comment: I think the issue is my popup conent is inside body-component..header is another component

Comment: Are you importing the components correctly? You would need to export whichever component and then import that component into the other one. Do you have your Angular Code (js)?